# Cannot access BIOS after changing the settings to Legacy Mode on Lenovo

Tags: windows, boot, bios, lenovo-laptop

TL;DR Changed BIOS settings from UEFI to Legacy Mode to boot from USB, installed Windows and now cannot access BIOS on Lenovo laptop.

I tried to dual boot my Lenovo laptop, managed to get it to work fine however a failed update caused the Linux distro to no longer work. After wiping the disk, I installed Windows 8.1 without remembering I had left the BIOS settings in Legacy Mode.

The end result is, I can boot however cannot access the BIOS to change any settings.

I have tried the usual suspects (F2, SHIFT, DEL, F12...) to boot into the BIOS however no luck. Tried wiping the disk completely and that doesn't provide any BIOS options.

Is there any way I can use a live USB to boot into the BIOS? When Windows 8.1 was installed there was no option to access the BIOS (through the advanced system startup options).

Any other tips and guidence to access the BIOS would be much appeaciated.

The laptop in question is a Lenovo Yoga.

Comment: Hold the shift key down when you select Shutdown from the start menu. Power up and see if you can enter bios now.

Comment: You don't have BIOS on this particular machine you have UEFI which supports legacy mode.  *There is a huge difference despite any graphics or menu items saying otherwise*  Proper terminology is important  If Windows 8.1 works use `Advance Startup` to access your UEFI settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I can boot however cannot access the BIOS to change any settings.

> **How to access the BIOS Setup**
>
> Press the button marked with the red arrow in the picture below:
>
> - Press the button when the Y3P is off!
> - Use a small pointing device, I use the tablet pen of one of my Thinkpad tablets

You may need to press and hold this Novo button pressed for a few seconds.

> [image]
>
> Once you press the button you will be presented with the following
>   screen:
>
> [image]
>
> Use the cursor keys to move up and down, press Enter to choose an
>   option.
>
> **BIOS Setup**
>
> The BIOS is where you can get technical information about your device,
>   as well to change boot parameters and setting up security passwords.
>   Be very careful when changing certain values, since it can affect the
>   way the Y3P works and/or affect performance and security settings.

See the source link below for details of the individual BIOS screens.

Source [Yoga 3 Pro - Accessing BIOS, boot menu and System Recovery](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Yoga-3-Pro-Accessing-BIOS-boot-menu-and-System-Recovery/ta-p/1809313)

Comment: Thanks! The manual I recieved with the laptop showed the one-key recovery on the other side of the PC. You've saved me a lot of headache

Comment: @MySQuirreL You're very welcome ;)